# What's the interaction between Dominated and Panicked?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, fear

Let's say there's a creature that's been dominated to attack the party. The party then uses a spell on that creature that causes them to be panicked for several rounds. Would the fact that you have the creature dominated mean they could be forced to act even though they desperately wanted to flee?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This DM would rule that even a *dominated* subject that's ordered by its master to turn and fight won't obey that order if the *dominated* creature suffers from the condition panicked. A *dominated* subject isn't immune to conditions, and commands from the master won't typically remove a *dominated* subject's conditions. The master of a *dominated* subject can't order that subject unimpaired if it's blinded, order it unawed if rebuked, or order it freed if entangled. I mean, the master *could*, but that order wouldn't end the condition. The same goes for the conditions shaken, frightened, panicked, and—if using the *Rules Compendium*—cowering.

However, a DM that wants some variance anyway may rule that for a *dominate* effect to overcome a fear effect, the subject's master must [compete for mental control](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#multiple-mental-control-effects) (also see *Player's Handbook* 172) against the creator of the fear effect for an effect's (*ahem*) dominance, but this DM would keep things simple and consistent and say a *dominated* subject that's panicked is simply panicked until the panicked condition abates.

Comment: I feel the analogies of blinded or entangled are kinda weak here, since Dominate is purely mental.

Comment: @StephenTG Would you rather the analogy included more perceived-as-mental conditions instead? I mean, that's a fine critique, and I can edit the answer accordingly, but the point remains the same: *dominate* isn't *remove fear* anymore than it's *remove blindness/deafness* or *freedom of movement*.